# Have only 1 div toggle instead of all

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

running into issues of trying to have only 1 div toggle instead of them all toggle. I've tried using `next()` and setting the selector to the `children` as opposed to the parent element, but then it won't toggle open at all.

FIDDLE:
http://jsfiddle.net/L415g07n/2/

What I am specifically trying to accomplish?
Have the selected div toggle when `.toggle` is clicked instead of all of them being toggled at once.

```
var c1 = $("#o");
var c2 = $("#t");
var c3 = $("#th");
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(c1).hide(0).delay(500).fadeIn(1500);
    $(c2).hide(0).delay(1500).fadeIn(1500);
    $(c3).hide(0).delay(2500).fadeIn(1500);
});
var content = $("#main .column .body");
$(content).hide();
var t1 = $(".toggle");
$(t1).click(function () {
    $(content).slideToggle('slow');
    $(t1).toggleClass("toggle");
    $(t1).toggleClass("toggle-d");
});
```

Comment: you'll want to use the $(this) selector so that you can apply the style to the current selected element only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `this` object and traverse to the required nodes,

```
$(t1).click(function () {
   $(this).toggleClass("toggle")
          .toggleClass("toggle-d")
          .parent().next('.body').slideToggle('slow');
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L415g07n/3/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's `$(this)` alows you to apply your effects on the current element. Here's the correct, shorter and simpler version of your code:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".column, .body").hide(); // you should put this in your CSS ( .column, .body { display: none; } )

    $(".column").each(function(index) {
        $(this).delay(400*index).fadeIn(300);
    });

    $(".toggle").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("toggle").toggleClass("toggle-d").parent().next(".body").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Notice, how you can even improve the part when your divs fade in, by reffering to them with a class name instead of id by using `$(this)` and `.each()`.

I think [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/) explains `$(this)` quite nicely.